# HTML Portfolio Template, separated into components using React, scroll does not work, only jumps to part of the page

Tags: html, reactjs, scroll, nav

I am a beginner in coding and am stuck with a navbar that has a scroll. I downloaded a template of a single page HTML portfolio which has a side navbar and on each click for each item it scrolls to the part of the page and underlines the selected item in yellow. I separated the HTML file into several components. I have a public folder where I copied all style and fonts files. My page displays just perfect, however the scroll does not work, it just jumps to the specific part of the page. Also the yellow line on each item does not work on 2 particular links. I am not sure what the issue is. I have read about a react scroll bar but like to believe that regular html should work as well? Please let me know if you need more code. Thank you for any suggestions!

```html
` enter code here
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <header className="fixed-top">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-12 navbar-header p-0">
                <a className="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#home">
                  <img src="img/my_logo.png" alt="myLogo" />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col-12 p-0">
                <nav id="navigation" className="nabar navbar-expand-xl">
                  <div id="navbarMorley" className="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav navbar-nav-yellow">
                      <li className="nav-item">
                        <a href="#home" className="nav-link page-scroll">
                          Home
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li className="nav-item">
                        <a href="#about" className="nav-link page-scroll">
                          About Me
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li className="nav-item">
                        <a href="#experience" className="nav-link page-scroll">
                          Resume
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li className="nav-item">
                        <a href="#skills" className="nav-link page-scroll">
                          Skills
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li className="nav-item">
                        <a href="#portfolio" className="nav-link page-scroll">
                          Portfolio
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </nav>
              </div>
              <div className="col-12 d-none d-xl-block navbar-footer p-0">
                <p className="m-0">
                  © My Name
                  <br />
                  All rights reserved 2020
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}


  `
```

Comment: "however the scroll does not work, it just jumps to the specific part of the page" - if it jumps to the correct place then it works - you probably want it to transition smoothly with a scroll animation - If that's how the code you're copying from worked it means you've not copied or loaded all the styles - this tutorial will help you with smooth scrolling https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling

Comment: "Also the yellow line on each item does not work on 2 particular links." - you need to post you're styles to debug that problem. If it works for some of the links you should compare what's different between the links for which it works and the links for which it doesn't. Usually it's a typo in a className in the html or in the css styles

Comment: @kidorca, you were correct. I forgot to copy the body tag. Problem fixed. I though I was doing something else wrong and therefore did not think to check the probably most obvious problem. Thanks for the hint, that helped!